# vim plugin ctrlp cant find some file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ctrlp

OSX 10.11.5

Vim 7.4

CtrlP https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim.git

I'm trying to use ctrlp to find App.cs in my project,  but I can't find it using CtrlP.

My only vim config about ctrlp is

```
let g:ctrlp_max_files = 0
```

[image]

Comment: You might not have set path. Did you included your project path in `:set path=`. Put this in your vmiimrc file and try again.

Comment: @SibiCoder    :set path?       path=.,/user/include,,

Comment: I think that's the problem. Can you include your project file path or the path of the files reside, in set path. For example, if your file is in /home/ming/sub/a.pl, then you will have to include like, :set path+=/home/ming/**.    ** means that you are including subdirectories as well

Comment: @SibiCoder I include my project file path     :set path      path=.,/usr/include,,,~/GitLab/client/**       But it does not work.

Comment: Just open our vim. Then, start typing a folder name in any file, and then press Ctrl+x and Ctrl+o, you will see the subfolders shown for completion. After that, delete the line. Then, try including completion of a function or a variable  from a file residing in ~/GitLab/client directory . it should work.

Comment: omnifun is not set      when press ctrl+x and ctrl+o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114576/discussion-between-mingchaoyan-and-sibicoder).

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.